# PutBucketPolicy Access Denied problem with S3 bucket policy even though assumed role has access

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have an IAM role (MyRole) with S3 and CloudFormation full access policies attached, and a trust relationship like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:root",
        "Service": [
          "cloudformation.amazonaws.com",
          "s3.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a group defined with this policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/MyRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

I created a user in that group and a config and credentials file to assume the role:

```
$ cat ~/.aws/config
[profile MyRole_role]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/MyRole
source_profile = profile1

$ cat ~/.aws/credentials
[profile1]
aws_access_key_id = A*********E7NT
aws_secret_access_key = 1a**************lVa
```

In a CloudFormation template I try to add a bucket policy:

```
Resources:

  MyS3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Description: Chris test bucket and policy
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref BucketName
      AccessControl: Private
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
        IgnorePublicAcls: true
        RestrictPublicBuckets: true

  MyS3BucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref MyS3Bucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          -
            Action:
              - s3:*
            Effect: Allow
            Resource:
              - !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${MyS3Bucket}
              - !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${MyS3Bucket}/*
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - '*'
```

I kick off the CloudFormation template with "--profile MyRole_role", and the bucket gets created but I always get a "API: s3:PutBucketPolicy Access Denied" error and the stack rolls back. In the IAM policy sim I never find any problems with being able to use S3:PutBucketPolicy. With the cli I can do something like a 's3 ls --profile MyRole_role" and it works fine, which makes me think my user is assuming the role. If I use "--profile profile1" I get an expected access denied. What could I be missing? Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Your bucket policy is very, very terrible from security point. Maybe its good you get access deny. But anyway, how do you know you can even create a bucket policy?Your role or user that you use to deploy the template has no permission to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your comment- I appreciate input on the security! It's really just a test at this point, but I'm puzzled by the fact that the role my user assumes has S3FullAccess, and yet is denied s3:PutBucketPolicy.

Comment: Did you disable public settings on your account and s3 bucket?

Comment: No, my account can set a bucket to either public or not, and my cloudformation template can set the bucket either way- it's just when I try to put a bucket policy with the template I get the access denied.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should turn off "block all public access".

with cloudformation you can you below define

```
        PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
          BlockPublicAcls: false
          BlockPublicPolicy: false
          IgnorePublicAcls: false
          RestrictPublicBuckets: false
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the issue is due you still have enabled the "Block all Public Access" on your S3 Account.

UnCheck it, and try again, it should work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.
It was missing the PutBucketPolicy permissions in my user.

**Steps:**

- Go to [aws policies](https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/iamv2/home#/policies)
- Add s3:PutBucketPolicy action policy for a specific bucket. In my case I just added for all s3 resources:

[image]

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
      }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in false:

```
BlockPublicAcls: true
BlockPublicPolicy: true
IgnorePublicAcls: true
RestrictPublicBuckets: true
```

Then upload an update to set to true again.